# How to delete a file named "~" in Mac?

Tags: macos, shell

I run the following command on my Macbook:

```
mkdir ~/tmp/~
```

Now, I want to delete this `~/tmp/~`
. 
How to do it? It is not a link actually, if I run `rm -rf ~/tmp/~`, the home files are all dropped.

Comment: For me, on OS X 10.10.1, `rm -rf ~/tmp/~` doesn't delete the home folder, it deletes the `~` directory inside ~/tmp as expected. So I am not sure why you are having a problem".

Comment: Likewise can't reproduce the claim that `rm -rf ~/tmp/~` is destructive.

Answer (score 3):

So interesting. This task can be done in this way.

```
# This form is safe and functional.
rm -rf ~/tmp/~
```

---

But if you try to do this, your home data is going to be lost:

```
# THIS FORM IS DANGEROUS; DO NOT USE IT
cd ~/tmp
rm -rf ~
```

Comment: I've tried to improve the grammar a bit -- since the only reason I can think of for this to be downvoted is if someone didn't understand it; it's quite correct as given.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Ivan X in his comment, the `~` in this context does not cause any particular problems and `rmdir ~/tmp~` removes the directory without problem (see #1 below).

However, what you describe is a classic Unix/BSD problem. In order to remove a directory that contains special characters you have to make sure your shell ignores interpolation of them.  There are two methods to achieve this.

1. You can use a full path, e.g. `rmdir ~/tmp/~` or...
2. In the case of a file or directory starting with `-`, you can use `--` to tell the shell that there are no options following, ala `rmdir -- -foo-`

Answer (score 0):

> So interesting. This task can be done in this way.
>
> ```
> # This form is safe and functional.
> rm -rf ~/tmp/~
> ```
>
> ---
>
> But if you try to do this, your home data is going to be lost:
>
> ```
> # THIS FORM IS DANGEROUS; DO NOT USE IT
> cd ~/tmp
> rm -rf ~
> ```

Quite so, and quite simply because (see [Tilde Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Tilde-Expansion)):

> If a word begins with an unquoted tilde character
>   (‘~’), all of the characters up to the first
>   unquoted slash (or all characters, if there is no unquoted slash) are
>   considered a tilde-prefix. If none of the characters in the
>   tilde-prefix are quoted, the characters in the tilde-prefix following
>   the tilde are treated as a possible login name. If this
>   login name is the null string, the tilde is replaced with the value of
>   the `HOME` shell variable.

Thus, `rm -rf ~` is expanded as `rm -rf $HOME`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my experience if it benefits someone else,
MacBook Pro, MacOS Montery, Version 12.6.5:

I accidentally created the tilde directory under my home directory
`~/work/xyz/~` and
when I tried to delete it as explained in many other places I kept getting an error of
`rmdir: ./~: Directory not empty`

Then I realized I had other directories and files inside of it (also accidentally while to trying to log the output of a process from a script) like:

`~/work/xyz/~/out/qa/xyz.log`

and similar such files, so I deleted them one by one and then ascending the directories also one by one:

```
cd ~/work/xyz
rm ./~/out/qa/xyz.log
rm ./~/out/qa/abc.log
...
rmdir ./~/out/qa
rmdir ./~/out
rmdir ./~/
```

and that did it. Good luck.

Answer (score -1):

Deletion of any file with a funny name is better done with a File browser. It is simply easier and safer.

If you don't want to use Finder, use any other text based file browser, e.g. emacs dired mode.

[...]

In case you insist in doing this using a shell...

```
 ls -i # will show you the inode number of the files you have
```

Once you have the right inode, say 123456789, you can use `find` to delete it.

```
 find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -inum 123456789 -delete
```

Comment: I'm not sure about "safer" in an entirely general sense -- using a shell is perfectly safe once you know what you're doing with it (quoting everywhere necessary to avoid expansion &c). That said, this remains good advice. I might add a `-maxdepth 1` to the `find` command to avoid recursion, if you're passing it the path straight to the directory with the file you want to delete.

Comment: nearly every single tool is perfectly safe once you know what you are doing with it ;-) my point is that a FileBrowser leaves less room for beginner mistakes than the shell.